# D3 set elements to transition in order

Tags: d3.js

I have some already existing elements in my script, to which I want to apply a staggered transition. I am selecting the different elements by their unique classes like so and doing the transitions:

```
  d3.selectAll('.first,.second,.third,.fourth')
   .transition()
     .duration(250)
   .transition()
     .delay(function(d,i){console.log(d); return i*5000})
       .style('fill','black')
```

However, the elements are not transition in the order of `first`->`second`->`third`->`fourth`, as they are shown in the `selectAll`. They appear to be quite random, although maybe this has to with how they show up in the DOM. How can I get them to transition in the order I have in `selectAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unaware of the capability of a D3 selection keeping the order of the different classes you pass to the `selectAll` function, and I believe what you want is simply not possible. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_selectAll), `selectAll`:

> Selects all elements that match the specified selector string. The elements will be selected in **document order**, top-to-bottom. (emphasis mine)

Thus, `selectAll(".foo,.bar")` and `selectAll(".bar,.foo")` have no difference.

However, if you want to apply the transition in the order of the different classes you're passing in your code, I'd like to propose this workaround: use an **array** with your classes and a `forEach`.

In this demo, I'm purposely setting the classes of the circles in an "unordered" way:

```
["second", "first", "fourth", "third", "first"]
```

Then, the `forEach` simply gets each class in the order you want (in this case, `'.first,.second,.third,.fourth'`) and applies the transition:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(["second", "first", "fourth", "third", "first"])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 30)
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => 40 + 40 * i)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("class", d=>d)
  .style("fill", "lightgray");
  

["first", "second", "third", "fourth"].forEach(function(d,i){
  d3.selectAll("."+d).transition()
    .duration(250)
    .transition()
    .delay(1000 + i*1000)
    .style('fill', 'black')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured a loop for a fallback.